# Debug Python code that requires console input

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm

How do you debug the code in the `PyCharm` IDE when it requires console input? For example, I have a piece of code,

```
        # if the config  already exists prompt what to do
        if pc and not self.prompt.ask_yesno('project_ovverride'):
            self.prompt.say('setup_abort')
            return
```

[image]

This breaks in the line highlighted and I wasn't able to proceed for not being able to provide the console input. At the moment, I comment it out, but, there might be a way to provide the required console input as well.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Pycharm 2018.3 or above you can redirect your input to a file.
PS. I haven't tried this but it should work fine.
[image: Set your input file here]

Comment: Your answer helps me. Thank you.

Comment: @Arefe use this if you are expecting multiple iterations of debugging and fixing. It really saves time.

Answer (score 2):

If you're simply looking to input via `CLI` while debugging; you could simply use `step into` as shown below. - Enable 'Run with console' under your run configuration first.

1. Change tab to `console` in your debugger.
2. Click on `step into` until you see the question in the console.
3. Input your answer as needed.
4. Click on `continue` or any other action from your debugger as needs be.

If you'd like to debug through running a script in `CLI` you're looking for something on the lines of `pdb` (Python Debugger). You can read more [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html#module-pdb).

**Example:**

**my_example.py**

```
try:
    pdb_test = 1 / 0
except ZeroDivisionError:
    print('Argh stop it!')
```

**Command Line:**

```
(venv) $ python3 -m pdb my_example.py
> /my_example.py(1)<module>()
-> try:
(Pdb) s
> /my_example.py(2)<module>()
-> a = 1 / 0
(Pdb) s
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
> /my_example.py(2)<module>()
-> a = 1 / 0
(Pdb)
```

What the above is showing is merely me using `s` to command the `pdb` to `step` - in the documentation you can find all the commands you might want to use including `continue` et cetera.

Comment: Your answer helps me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Initially, we need to set the `Run with Python console` in the Run configuration of the PyCharm IDE and then, we can change the debugger window to the console window at the time of debugging the software. I provided the screenshots that illustrate the formula,

[image]

Now, switch from the debugger to the console and provide the desired input.

[image]